# conrod bearing segments

Tags: engine, diesel, repair

[image]I'm building a 1.9 td PSA motor, type DHX and ordering new segments I found the mark on all the segments on the same side, I've checked again and again and all indications are that the item description nº is correct, yet on the closing end they fit perfectly but on the rod side it should be different. [image]Meaning 4 segments the mark should be on the left and the other 4 should be right, ,... my question is that normal, if so wrong packaging if not ,... what went wrong here,.. how to fix,... I don't think I could place it in the rod end side with the mark on corresponding the segment. Thank you

Comment: Need to see some images here as I have not followed what you are trying to explain...

Comment: how could I upload images

Comment: When you created your question (and when you edit it) there is a small box roughly top middle with what looks like mountains in it - click on that and drop the image file in the window - classic drag and drop...

Comment: As you can see the segments all came mark on same side, but it requires a left and a right mark to insert.

Comment: Looks like the rod cap is on backwards to me.

Comment: ya, that's exactly my problem, how do I now put a wrong mark segment in the place,..

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the two images, the bearing shell on the left in the top image will go in the rod on the right-hand side and the right bearing shell on the left part of the con rod.

Comment: That's just the point, the problem is when you turn the segment around to place it, the mark on the segment is on the other side

Comment: I note that you have a new shell already in the rhs of the con-rod... But my explanation still stands.

Comment: @KobusvanWyk - From the pictures you provided, as long as the top picture is of the NEW bearings, I'm not seeing an issue here. They don't look new in the picture, though. In the bottom picture, the bearing you have in the connecting rod cap looks to be brand new without blemishes. If the top picture is not the new bearings, you might want to show us them so we can understand better what you're saying.

Comment: @Solar Mike ya the top one has the two old segments, now try and put another with the mark same way on other side, eg in the bottom picture, -new one should have segment mark on oposite site to be able to fit, but there all same side marking.

Comment: Top one are the old bearing, inside the conrod ,.. that's a new bearing, all are like that one..

Comment: That new one - is the "ear" or tab bent out? If not then it may rotate in use and starve the oil flow...